# How to dynamically build pages in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have the following problem:

I have an object, it is representing a list of "pages" and "quests" whithin them

```
  <div ng-repeat='page in pages' ng-show='page.show'>
       ....
  </div>
```

Now, when i render them, i did ng-show on, for example page 1, and then when user click a next button, the ng-shows shows the next page.

That was "ok" till now, but now i need something like this:

I need this pages to be routes.. like if my site is www.mysite.com/pages/

than page one will be represented this way www.mysite.com/pages/#1

and the reason is that when a user clicks "back" i want to use history.js to let the user go back to where he came from...

How should i tackle this? where should i start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its pretty interesting to generate dynamic pages and keeping stack of routing. So you must look into this [ngDynamicRouting](https://github.com/GrumpyWizards/ngDynamicRouting). What it does is simplify your code such as you don't need to setup new routes for new pages. Here we go..

**Config**
First you have to specify generic route

```
$routeProvider.when('pages/:pageNumber', { templateUrl: 'partials/blank.html', controller: PagesController });
```

**Controller**

```
function PagesController($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $compile) {
    // Here I am assuming you are having list of pages in pages array.
    //make sure you validate the pageNumber some where. 
    $route.currentPage = $scope.pages[$routeParams.pageNumber];
}
PagesController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$routeParams', '$compile'];
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-show="currentPage">
```

Let me know if it fixes your problem. if not than try to provide me a plunker or fiddle.

Thanks